# Is it safe and legitimate to use std::experimental features in a library released to the public?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, c++-experimental

Suppose I'm writing a library which targets C++14-capable compilers.

In C++14, several standard library facilities were introduced as experimental, e.g. `optional` and `filesystem`.

Is it:

1. safe (for downstream developers)
2. legitimate

for me to utilize these features in my library even if only C++14 is supported? e.g. in the form

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201703L
#include <optional>
namespace mylib {
using std::optional;
using std::nullopt;
}
#else
static_assert(__cplusplus >= 201402L, "C++2014 is required to compile this program");
#include <experimental/optional>
namespace mylib {
using std::experimental::optional;
using std::experimental::nullopt;
}
#endif
```

Note: Of course, I mean in the case of downstream developers actually having to use these features themselves, not just for the case when I use them internally only with no outside exposure.

Comment: Are these experimental libraries necessarily shipped with the standard library?

Comment: @Evg: 1. Yes, although for libstdc++ you need to specify an extra linker flag to get `std::filesystem`. 2. optional is a header-only feature, so at least in some cases it doesn't matter.

Comment: In my experience the experimental headers are only 99% similar to the subsequent release. I’ve found differences in every single one I’ve used.

Comment: @Dani: I assumed as much. But - that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Wouldn't be more "portable" to rely to an external library, like `boost`? Different compilers may have very different implementations and support for experimental features.

Comment: @Bob__: Using Boost has its pros and cons. But I didn't ask what would be the _best_ thing to do, I just asked if this is legitimate.

Comment: It seems legitimate, at least in one similar scenario.  This is basically like the `std::tr1` headers that shipped with Visual C++ 2010 and below compilers, but the author wanted to target newer compilers and the older compilers.  Thus the author `#ifdef`-ed the namespace to either `std::` or `std::tr1`.